# Events in reputation tab are not grouped correctly

Tags: bug, reputation, user-interface, profile-page

I noticed this error on the reputation tab:

1. You must have multiple events under a single post.
2. At least two of those events have occurred since you last opened your reputation page; at least two of those events occurred earlier.
3. These events must have occurred on the same day.
4. You must view the events by group by post.

You will see two groups of events. This is expected:

[image: collapsed groups]

However, if you expand either of these groups, you will see all the events for that post, not just the events for that group:

[image: expanded groups]

Ideally, it should look like this:

[image: corrected groups]